# Ruby で Gmail のラベル付きメールを読み取りたい

Tags: ruby, gmail

Rubyで Gmail の メールを受信して本文にあるテキストを読み取りたいです。

こんなことは可能でしょうか。

1. Ruby のメールライブラリ "Mail" を使用して Gmail の "cat"ラベルのついた一番新しいメールを読み取る
2. Ruby の Gmail 読み取りライブラリ "ruby-gmail" を 使用して "cat" ラベルの付いた一番新しいメールを読み取る

・Gmail の IMAP 有効化済み
・Google アカウントの「安全性の低いアプリの許可」を「有効」に変更済み

という状況だと考えてください。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ruby-gmail gem をベースに開発されている [gmail gem](https://github.com/gmailgem/gmail) を使います。

以下のコードを実行すると "cat"ラベルが付いた最新メールの件名と本文が出力されます。

```
require 'gmail'

username = 'PUT YOUR USERNAME' # Gmailのユーザ名
password = 'PUT YOUR PASSWORD' # Gmailのパスワード

label_name = 'cat' # 対象のラベル名

Gmail.connect(username, password) do |gmail|
  email = gmail.label(label_name).emails.first

  puts 'subject: ' + email.subject
  puts 'body: ' + email.body.decoded.encode('UTF-8', email.charset)
end
```

Comment: 素晴らしいコードに感動です！！

Comment: `email.html_part.decoded` でメールのHTMLを取得することも可能です

Comment: `email.text_part.decoded` でメールのテキストを取得することも可能です